# How to split multipages editor in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

Eclipse allow users to split the Editor Area into  more one space, giving ability to display two files at the same time ( or the same file if you duplicate it using Window->New Editor)

Is there anyway to split the editor window itself into multiple areas for editors with multiple pages ?
e.g.
Assume you are opening plugin.xml file, and you want to view "plugin.xml" tab/page next to "Extensions" tab/page.

The hard way is :
_- Open the desired plugin.xml file
_- From top toolbar, select  Window->New Editor
_- Split the editor area into two areas
_- Select "plugin.xml" tab/page in one editor, and "Extension" tab/page in the other eidtor.

I would like to drag the tab/page to split just like we do for different editor.
If Eclipse does not provide that, Is it doable in custom editor , if Yes then How?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

No you can't do this with the multipage editors. These editors use the `CTabFolder` control to show the pages and this control only supports showing one page at a time.

Not sure what you mean by a `custom editor`. You could write a separate editor for each page so that you could then open these editors separately, which would allow the split. However this would be a huge amount of work.

Comment: I meant with 'custom editor', my own editor with multiple pages. So I can not split in Eclipse nature multiple pages editors due to implementation limitations, can I avoid these limitation in my own multiple page editor so I can allow page split.  If Yes, then any idea how ? What is the required changes in normal multiple page editor implementation to allow page split ?